# What are all the Secret Achievements in Fruit Ninja?

Tags: achievements, fruit-ninja

What are all the Secret Achievements in Fruit Ninja? I've been playing for a while but only got the one for getting a score of 99.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ones I got are:

- Got a score of 50 in Classic Mode
- Got a score of 100 in Classic Mode
- Got a Score of 200 in Classic Mode
- Killed 150 Fruit Total
- Killed 500 Fruit Total
- Killed 1000 Fruit Total
- Killed 5000 Fruit Total
- Killed 10000 Fruit Total
- Killed 10 Bananas in one round of Classic Mode
- Killed 15 Apples in one round of Classic Mode
- Killed 20 Plums in one round in Classic Mode
- Got 6 criticals in one round in Classic Mode
- Killed 3 Pears in a row in Classic Mode
- Got a critical hit with a Mango
- Killed 4 of the same type of fruit in a row in Classic Mode
- Secret (placeholder)
- Failed with a score of 0
- Failed with a score of 69
- Failed with a score of 99
- Sliced 6 fruit in one combo
- Archived a score of 200 in Zen Mode
- Sliced 10 Coming Soon fruit
- Slice the secret fruit!
- Get the Lovely Bunch star in Zen Mode
- Got a score over 400 after all bonuses in Arcade Mode
- Got a score less than 20 after all bonuses in Arcade Mode
- Hit three bombs ans scored over 250 after all bonuses in Arcade Mode.
- You are relentless in your pursuit of perfection! (restarted a game 3 times)
- Complete 3 games between the hours of 2am and 5am
- Post a score to Facebook or Twitter

Answer (score 14):

The secrets are getting 0, 69, 99; losing with your same high score,
slicing the banana 20 times, and hitting no fruit in zen mode.

Comment: I think you ought to change that to 'coming soon' banana...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there's one where you cut this super rare dragon fruit. It pops out out of nowhere; you just have to wait. There's another one where you have to match your highscore without going over. Then there's another one where you cut 10 secret fruit. That's all I know.