# How do I get the perfection achievement in Fruit Ninja?

Tags: achievements, fruit-ninja

I have every other achievement in Fruit nNinja and all I can find on it is the description the game gives you, which is "You are relentless in your pursuit of perfection!"

Comment: A somewhat related question about some of the secret achievements can be found on this question, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7785/what-are-all-the-secret-achievements-in-fruit-ninja , but there are no descriptions of the non-obvious ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this achievement by going into Classic mode, slicing one fruit, and then restarting. Do this 3 times in a row, and after the third restart, you should get the achievement.

I found this information [here](http://gameachievements.org/achievements/view/7281), but I did try it out and confirmed it on the iPhone version.